# Using Fancybox to bring up video-js iframe issue

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, fancybox

Alright so I am trying to use Fancybox to bring up a iframe that has a video in it when an image banner is clicked.  After various attempts and going through a lot of documentation the only thing I have managed so far is make myself cry.  At the moment when the image is clicked your taken to fluvid.html and the video plays full screen.I was thinking that I need another eye on my code.  What is it I am missing here?
In head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 640,
    maxHeight   : 360,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : true,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});
});
</script>
```

Image code:

```
<div class="flubanner"><a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="fluvid.html"><img src="images/flubanner.png" height="200px" width="980px"/></a></div>
```

fluvid.html

```
<div class="video-js-box">
<!-- Using the Video for Everybody Embed Code http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody -->
<video id="fluvid" class="video-js" width="640px" height="360px" controls="controls" preload="auto" autoplay poster="images/image.jpg">
  <source src="images/fluvid.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
     <!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. -->
    <img src="images/image.jpg" width="640" height="360" alt="Poster Image"
  title="No video playback capabilities." />
</video>
```

Comment: did you load jQuery, then fancybox css and js files (in that order)?

Comment: Yes I did.  I had the fancybox working with jwplayer, however there was a problem the video so I switched to video-js thinking it would be easier.  Here is a link to the site, if you need the full code: [link](www.empireclinicalresearch.com)

Comment: I figured it out, I had loaded the jQuery twice in the page using another plugin.